# Display QQmlComponent in QQuickWidget

Tags: qt, qtquick2

According to QQuickWidget's [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html):

> you can instantiate your own objects using QQmlComponent and place
>   them in a manually set up QQuickWidget.

But I can't find any example of that. I would like to have multiple QQmlComponents loaded into RAM and display them in QQuickWidget depending on which one is active. Any idea on how to display any content in QQuickWidget except for setSource()?

Comment: Do you want to load a QQmlComponent without using setSource()?

Comment: Yes, as setSource works with filenames/urls only

Comment: when you create a QQmlComponent you have to pass it a QQmlEngine, and if you want it to be shown in the QQuickWidget you must pass the QQmlEngine of the QQuickWidget: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html#engine

Comment: what is the meaning of *depending on which one is active*?

Comment: I mean that somewhere there will be QComboBox which defines which component to show in QuickWidget. I've just found `QQuickWidget::setContent()` which supposed to do that. But it's documentation is hidden (QTBUG-59220) for some reason... Testing it..

Comment: According to what they indicate is that it is an internal method so it will probably be released in future versions or be eliminated.

Comment: Well, this func was introduced in 5.3 and according to github wasn't changed since then. And it's still work in my 5.9. I would assume that they've added this function but unsure if it's really needed so not promoting it.

Answer (score 1):

I've end up with following solution: create new `QQuickWidget` widget and use its `QQuickWidget::setContent()` to display already created QML content in it. It works in my Qt 5.9.

Note: `setContent()` is [marked](https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/5.11/src/quickwidgets/qquickwidget.cpp#L586) as **internal** and have some drawbacks although this API is public and available in public header.

First of all, `QQuickWidget` doesn't clear its content when `QQuickWidget::setContent()` is consequently called for different data. So old and new content overlaps. That's why I have to create a new `QQuickWidget` on every content change and replace old `QQuickWidget` with new fresh one.

Secondly, `QQuickWidget` thinks it owns pointers passed via `QQuickWidget::setContent()` and tries to delete content at destruction. To bypass this you may execute `QQuickWidget::setContent(QUrl(), nullptr, nullptr)` before `QQuickWidget` instance is destroyed. But this triggers a warning message from QML engine in stdout about incorrect qml content. So better approach is to set dummy data:

```
QQmlComponent* dummy = new QQmlComponent(engine);
dummy->setData(QByteArray("import QtQuick 2.0; Item { }"), QUrl());
wgt->setContent(dummy->url(), dummy, dummy->create());
wgt->deleteLater();
```

With these hacks I was able to load multiple QML objects (plugins with own UI) with `QQmlComponent` at runtime. Instantiate them and display one of them in QWidgets-based application depending on plugin selected.